# Filter a stream with multiple critera until a result is not null with Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, java-8, enums

I have an `ArrayList` of objects called `Student`.
I want to filter this list and return a **single** `Student` object only based on **hierarchical conditions**.

The conditions are as follows:

- Select the first COMP student.
- If none are returned, select an ECON student.
- If none are returned, select a AGRI student.
- ... etc.

In my design, I have hard coded this - but maybe it can use a sorted `Set` or `List` or something.

My current code works, but seems messy, and will grow quite large if more conditions are introduced.

I need help with the `Student filterStudent(List<Student> studentList)` method. How to do this in fewer lines of code maybe or method chaining. And how to introduce a sorted `Set` of `Enums` that can be filtered based on preference (Example, COMP first, if empty, then ECON next, etc. Stop filtering if one is found).

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

class Student {
    private final int stNumber;
    private final String stModule;//...more fields

    public Student(int stNumber, String stModule) {
        this.stNumber = stNumber;
        this.stModule = stModule;
    }

    public int getStNumber() {
        return stNumber;
    }

    public String getStModule() {
        return stModule;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "stNumber=" + stNumber +
                ", stModule='" + stModule + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

enum Module {
    COMP("Computers"),
    ECON("Economics"),
    AGRI("Agriculture"),
    PHYS("Physics"); //...very large list

    private String moduleName;

    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    Module(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }
}

public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //These lists can be any size and contain any information
        List<Student> studentListOne = Arrays.asList(
                new Student(41, "Economics"),
                new Student(45, "Computers")
        );

        List<Student> studentListTwo = Arrays.asList(
                new Student(11, "Physics"),
                new Student(23, "Agriculture"),
                new Student(86, "Physics"),
                new Student(34, "Economics")
        );

        List<Student> studentListThree = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println(filterStudent(studentListOne));
        System.out.println(filterStudent(studentListTwo));
        System.out.println(filterStudent(studentListThree)); //exception
    }

    /**
     * Rules are: Choose the first instance of a COMP student.
     * If the list is empty, choose a ECON student.
     * If the list is still empty, choose a AGRI student.
     *
     * @param studentList
     * @return Student
     */
    public static Student filterStudent(List<Student> studentList) throws Exception {
        Optional<Student> selectedStudent;

        selectedStudent = studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.getStModule().equalsIgnoreCase(Module.COMP.getModuleName())).findFirst();
        if (selectedStudent.isPresent()) {
            return selectedStudent.get();
        }

        selectedStudent = studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.getStModule().equalsIgnoreCase(Module.ECON.getModuleName())).findFirst();

        if (selectedStudent.isPresent()) {
            return selectedStudent.get();
        }

        selectedStudent = studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.getStModule().equalsIgnoreCase(Module.AGRI.getModuleName())).findFirst();

        if (selectedStudent.isPresent()) {
            return selectedStudent.get();
        }

        throw new Exception("No student found matching criteria");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your current method with a loop:

```
for (Module mod : Arrays.asList(Module.COMP, Module.ECON, Module.AGRI)) {
  String subj = mod.getModuleName();

  Optional<Student> selectedStudent = studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.getStModule().equalsIgnoreCase(subj)).findFirst();
  if (selectedStudent.isPresent()) {
    return selectedStudent.get();
  }
}
throw new Exception(...);
```

If you want to avoid iterating the list multiple times, you can declare a `Comparator<Student>`:

```
Map<String, Integer> ordering = Map.of(Module.COMP.getModuleName().toLowerCase(), 0, Module.ECON.getModuleName().toLowerCase(), 1, Module.AGRI.getModuleName().toLowerCase(), 2);
ToIntFunction<Student> studentOrdering = student -> ordering.getOrDefault(student.getModuleName().toLowerCase(), ordering.size());
Comparator<Student> comparator = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparingInt(studentOrdering));
```

A simple solution would then be to use `Stream.min`:

```
Optional<Student> student = studentList.stream().min(comparator);
```

and this is probably fine. If you want to do it with a more explicit list, you can stop as soon as you find a `COMP` student:

```
Student best = null;
for (Student student : studentList) {
  int comp = comparator.compare(best, student);
  if (comp > 0) {
    best = student;
    int studentOrder = studentOrdering.apply(student);
    if (studentOrder == 0) {
      // Can't find a better student, so fast break.
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (best != null) {
  return best;
}
throw new Exception(...);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of your first solution - its easy to read and understand. But how big of a performance impact will this have over your other solution and @ernest_k solution. Considering the filtering list would be max 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to support a dynamic list and order of selected modules is to filter the list, sort it and then pick the first element:

```
public static Student filterStudent(List<Student> studentList, List<String> moduleOrder)
        throws Exception {
    return studentList.stream().filter(s -> moduleOrder.contains(s.getStModule()))
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(student -> moduleOrder.indexOf(student.getSModule())))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("No student found matching criteria"));
}
```

And to execute your current logic, you can call it with the student list and something like `List.of(Module.COMP.getModuleName(), Module.ECON.getModuleName(), Module.AGRI.getModuleName())` as second argument.

This will avoid the repeated iterations over the list. But I'm assuming that the `moduleOrder` list is small, with a handful of elements as in your example (it is searched a few times for filtering and for sorting)

Comment: would `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(moduleOrder::indexOf))` without `map`ping work? I guess you would want to use the lambda there?

Comment: Thanks @Naman. Didn't compile that. Definitely a bug I'll correct now.

Comment: How about just using [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) directly? No need to sort.

Comment: `min()` is definitely better @AndyTurner

Comment: @ernest_k can you explain the line with `.min`. I tested it and it works - but why does it work?

Comment: @Leo Yes. It's minimum student by order of stModule in the `moduleOrder` list. The comparator is determining order by finding where the sudent's module is in that list.